# Blogger data tags don't work in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hy, I have some issues when adding blogger data tags to javascript.

```
var summary1 = '<div class="firstWrap">' + '<h3 class="post-title entry-title">' + '</h3>' + '<div>' + removeHtmlTag(div.innerHTML,summ) + '</div>' + '<span class="readmorebutton">' + '<a expr:href="data:post.url">' + 'Read More &#187;' + '</a>' + '</span>' + '</div>' + imgtag;
div.innerHTML = summary1;
}
```

The code adds the div first wrap the read more button and the summaries but it won't load the h3 and the a expr:href= data doesn't work.
How can I add the blogger data expr:href=... and other blogger code into javascript so that it works.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You must define the `expr:href="data:post.url"` via Javascript variable in separated `script` tag. Simply like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var postlink="<data:post.url/>"
</script>
```

You can place that script before or after your `entry-container`.

Then, call the variable in your script:

```
var summary1 = '<div class="firstWrap">' + '<h3 class="post-title entry-title">' + '</h3>' + '<div>' + removeHtmlTag(div.innerHTML,summ) + '</div>' + '<span class="readmorebutton">' + '<a href="'+postlink+'">' + 'Read More &#187;' + '</a>' + '</span>' + '</div>' + imgtag;
div.innerHTML = summary1;
}
```

I use this method in my blogger template, and it's works good for me.